# Libertine Font not found (texLive)

Tags: errors, pdftex, libertine

I am not an expert in Latex, so I'm sorry if I miss some information I should give you or if I'm missing something basic.

I have tried to download and install the "Libertine" package from CTAN as I usually do with any other package, by extracting the libertine.tds.zip on a personal folder with a texmf tree I have on my user home (I'm using texLive on linux Slackware, installed using http://slackbuilds.org/ package). However, when I try to call `\usepackage{libertine}` using pdftex (command texi2pdf) I get the following error:

```
(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd) [1{/usr/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./teste.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base): Font LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

TeX Output exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Feb 13 07:51:51
```

I have seen that there are some compatibility issues with libertine, but as far as I understood all those issues should be solved with the current libertine package on CTAN (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertine).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Here goes the full .log file produced by trying to compile a simple .tex:

.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

.log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016 on Slackware (SlackBuilds.org)) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.11)  13 FEB 2017 08:11
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**\input ./teste.tex
(./teste.tex (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
Package: libertine 2014/11/25 (Bob Tennent) Supports Libertine and Biolinum fon
ts for all LaTeX engines.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count87
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
)
(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty
Package: mweights 2016/12/09 (Bob Tennent) Support package for multiple-weight 
font packages. 
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bfseries on input line 21.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mdseries on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \rmfamily on input line 37.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sffamily on input line 56.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ttfamily on input line 75.
)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package
)
(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2014/03/23 v1.0d Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 31.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 33.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 37.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 478.

(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
(/home/vitor/BGSE/Econometrics-II/Presentation/tex/temp/teste.aux)
\openout1 = `teste.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for TS1+cmr on input line 5.

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OT1+LinuxLibertineT-TLF on
 input line 5.

(/home/vitor/texmf/tex/latex/libertine/OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd
File: OT1LinuxLibertineT-TLF.fd 2012/11/26 (autoinst) Font definitions for OT1/
LinuxLibertineT-TLF.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OT1/LinuxLibertineT-TLF/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 5.
\c@mv@tabular=\count88
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count89
 [1

{/usr/share/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(/home/vitor/BGSE/Econometrics-II/Presentation/tex/temp/teste.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2010 strings out of 493013
 34576 string characters out of 6139264
 70832 words of memory out of 5000000
 5584 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 5295 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,33p,169b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file LinLibertineT-tlf-ot1--base): Font LinLibertineT-
tlf-ot1--base at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: did you run `updmap-sys --enable Map=libertine.map` ??

Comment: @Herbert So I was really missing something basic. I got it working by running `chmod +x libertine.map`, then executing you command `updmap-sys --enable Map=libertine.map` as root in the directory where libertine.map was. If you want to post a solution I'll be happy to accept and perhaps help some other newbies like myself.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I usually recommend installing fonts in the local tree (`TEXMFLOCAL`) rather than the personal tree(`TEXMFHOME`), because this will have no impact when updates to fonts in the main tree happen. On the other hand, Libertine belongs to TeX Live, so you should be able to install it with tlmgr or whatever method is available on Slackware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install fonts which are part of TL in the texlive directory tree.
However, every font must be made known to the TeX system.

```
updmap-sys --enable Map=libertine.map
```

or with `sudo` if you'd install TL as root.

Answer (score 7):

I have {sudo} permissions and my current configuration is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I faced this warning while running the **ACM sigconf** conference proceedings format for a research paper submission. The warning message also showed that zi4 package was also missing. The following command resolved both those issues for me.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you use it as admin or user? Which operating system? Please explain better.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.