# Issues with libertine package

Tags: fonts, packages, ubuntu, linux, libertine

I would like to print a file (in Linux) and I get the following error

[image]

I have tried manually installing libertine but I have failed to do so.

When I dowloaded the zip folder, I extracted it, and then I dragged the latex folder (and renamed it as libertine) into
[image]

However, I still get the same error. Does anybody know of an easy way to install libertine? I would love to be able to do it with the sudo command...

Comment: you should be able to update via apt, not having to download by hand, probably `sudo apt update texlive-fonts-extra` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/473386/1090

Comment: Dear @DavidCarlisle I am sorry but this command does not work. It says I do not have enough space but I have 12 GB that I am not using.

Comment: sorry but apt config is off topic here, if i says you don't have space I'd believe it. is it using a different partition on the disk? That is in any case th command for updaing the debian texlive.

Comment: Hi. I managed to fix it. I think I have issues with the way the storage is partitioned. I am new to Linux and I thought that there is "overll storage" but I guess that storage is alocated to different things? I used the clean command in the terminal to free up space but I worry that I will get the same issue again.

Comment: OK we can close this as duplicae thn, glad you got it working